# Math equation a little hard for me

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this equation to solve.

Im not very good at equation.

**I got this equation**

$( A\times \cos(B) ) \times C = D$

**I want this form**

$( A \times ? ) \times \cos(B \times ?) = D$

I want to do something like merge **C** in **A** and **B** for giving the result **D**

Comment: First $?=C$, second $?=C/C$

Comment: Thanks you but I did explain my question well, I ll make another

Comment: use latex to write your question

Comment: What exactly the original exercise was?

Comment: Could you explain how your question relates to differential equations?

Comment: Sorry I would pick the tag "equation"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404576/equation-with-angle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have the equation: $(A\cdot \cos{B}) \cdot C = D$

Then by commutativity/associativity we can rewrite it as: $(A \cdot C) \cdot \cos{B} = D$

We can NOT "distribute" the $C$ in the way that you have suggested. That is, in general:

> - $(X \cdot Y) \cdot Z \ne (X \cdot Z) \cdot (Y \cdot Z)$
> - $(\cos{X}) \cdot Y \ne \cos(X \cdot Y)$